# When passing apostrophe to a String 'sql_query' ’ it comes in as \u2019

Tags: php, mysql

I am passing a query String in a mysqli_query just like

$SQL_query = SELECT REPLACE(description, '’', '') AS description FROM event WHERE event.event_title = 'we're ready';

$result = mysqli_query($link, $SQL_query);

When i debug REPLACE(description, '’', '') (from the PHP script present in cpanel) is passed as  REPLACE(description, '\u2019', '') to the sql console.

just like:
$SQL_query is passed as to SQL console
SELECT REPLACE(description, '\2019', '') AS description FROM event WHERE event.event_title = 'we're ready';

instead of 
SELECT REPLACE(description, '’', '') AS description FROM event WHERE event.event_title = 'we're ready';

I tried with LOWER(REPLACE(a.b, '\’', ''));
and htmlentites(LOWER(REPLACE(a.b, '’', '')));

and may more work arounds which i get by googling

which i want to pass apostrophe to a query string in PHP

Kindly help me with this

Comment: Could you please clarify what exactly are you trying to accomplish? The usage of single quotes (apostrophe) in a query is highly discouraged since this is extremely vulnerable and can cause a ton of issues.

Comment: [U+2019](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2019/index.htm) is not an apostrophe.

Comment: Why selecting `a.a` more than once ? Where is the `event` table in from clause ? Should it be `a.event` ? Are you trying to escape single quotes in the search term ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried escaping the apostrophe character ? like:

(a.b, '\’', ''))